# Is there a difference between `syntax on` and `syntax enable` in vimscript?

Tags: vim

In my .vimrc file I use:

```
syntax on
```

Today, I was perusing through some .vimrc files from other developers and i've notice a few using:

```
syntax enabled
```

Is there a difference? Are these both accomplishing the same goal just using different locution?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

### What Vim Claims

For `syntax on` vs `syntax enable`, the help files *claim*:

```
The ":syntax enable" command will keep your current color settings.  This
allows using ":highlight" commands to set your preferred colors before or
after using this command.  If you want Vim to overrule your settings with the
defaults, use: >
    :syntax on
```

### I Can't Verify These Claims

The behavior I see in Vim does not appear to match the above help statement.

After testing locally with some empty `.vimrc`s and experimenting with `on`, `enable`, and placement of highlight commands, I can't figure out what Vim is actually doing (I tested with `highlight ColorColumn guibg=#331111` and `set colorcolumn=80`). Highlighting is sometimes overwritten and sometimes not.

### Only Let Vim Set Syntax Once

I no longer trust Vim, so I only let syntax get set once, ever. Here's what I have in my `.vimrc`:

```
if !exists("g:syntax_on")
    syntax enable
endif
```

I use `enable` because of the above *claim* that it won't overwrite your settings, however it doesn't seem to make any difference when starting Vim.

## More details

You can see that `h g:syntax_on` shows that `on` and `enable` source the same file:

```
Details:
The ":syntax" commands are implemented by sourcing a file.  To see exactly how
this works, look in the file:
    command     file ~
    :syntax enable  $VIMRUNTIME/syntax/syntax.vim
    :syntax on      $VIMRUNTIME/syntax/syntax.vim
```

If you're curious, `g:syntax_on` gets set in `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/synload.vim`

Also running Vim with no plugins/settings `vim -u NONE` does NOT load any of the syntax files.

Comment: Ah! Perfect. Thanks for the breakdown @Andy. What exactly does the if statement safegaurd?

Comment: It prevents an unnecessary execution of code when you source your `.vimrc`.

Comment: I'm confused: you say "calling `syntax enable` [...] multiple times` will clobber any color highlighting", but then you quote Vim's help that say "`syntax enable` will keep your current color settings".  Which is it?

Comment: @MariusGedminas you're right, the answer is confusing I will update it

Comment: I still don't get it. Using `:syntax enable` for extra caution.